# How to narrow callback event type based on event name

Tags: typescript, events, callback

I'm trying to implement an event emitter. The code is very simple.

Right now `tsc` thinks that the event type in `eventHandler` is `'ErrorEvent' | 'MessageEvent'`.
This is the problem and I want `tsc` to narrow the types to the correct one (depending on `eventName` passed to the `on` function).

Can it be done?

**Definitions**

```
interface Event {
  code: string;
}

interface ErrorEvent extends Event {
  xxx: number;
}

interface MessageEvent extends Event {
  yyy: number;
}

interface Events {
  error: ErrorEvent,
  message: MessageEvent
}

type EventHandler = (event: Events[keyof Events]) => void;
```

**TS CODE**

```
function on (eventName: keyof Events, eventHandler: EventHandler) {
  console.log(eventName)
}

on('message', (event) => { // ErrorEvent | MessageEvent
  console.log(event)
  console.log(event.code)
  console.log(event.xxx) //  Property 'xxx' does not exist on type 'ErrorEvent | MessageEvent'.
  console.log(event.yyy) //  Property 'yyy' does not exist on type 'ErrorEvent | MessageEvent'.
})
```

Comment: quick and dirty "event as unknown as ErrorEvent" or vice versa wrapped in an if. But propably to dirty for most cases

Comment: @manidos I believe it will be helpful https://catchts.com/publish-subscribe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to get rid of EventHandler as a union type:

```
type EventHandler<K extends EventKeys> = (event: Events[K]) => void
```

That way you get a concrete type for you handler for each concrete `K`.
And then you make sure second argument type of the `on` function depends on the first one. Thus you have to introduce a type parameter to you function to get types in line:

```typescript
function on <K extends EventKeys>(eventName: K, eventHandler: EventHandler<K>): void {}
```

I believe this should do:

```typescript
interface Event {
  code: string;
}

interface ErrorEvent extends Event {
  xxx: number;
}

interface MessageEvent extends Event {
  yyy: number;
}

interface Events {
  error: ErrorEvent,
  message: MessageEvent
}

type EventKeys = keyof Events
type EventHandler<K extends EventKeys> = (event: Events[K]) => void;

function on <K extends EventKeys>(eventName: K, eventHandler: EventHandler<K>): void {
  console.log(eventName)
}

on('message', (event) => {
  console.log(event)
  console.log(event.code)
  console.log(event.xxx) //  Property 'xxx' does not exist on type 'MessageEvent<any>'.
  console.log(event.yyy)
})
```

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/w2608w)